# Derive Cherenkov radiation using four momentum

Tags: special-relativity, cherenkov-radiation

In vacuum, it is not possible for an electron to emit a single photon. That can be proved by using 4-momentum.

(Let $ c = 1 $)

Initially,
$$
P_e^{\mu}=\left(E_e, \mathbf{p}_e\right) 
$$
Finally,
$$P_e^{\prime \mu}=\left(E^\prime_e, \mathbf{p}_e^{\prime}\right) $$
$$P_\gamma^{\mu}=\left(p_\gamma, \mathbf{p}_\gamma\right) $$
so
$$  \left(P_e^\mu-P_\gamma^\mu\right)^2=P_e^{\prime \mu} $$
$$ 2 P_e^\mu P_\gamma^\mu=0 $$
$$p_e p_\gamma \cos \theta-p_\gamma E_e=0$$
Since $ p_e < E_e$ and $ \cos \theta < 1$, impossible!

However in medium with refractive index, that is possible and is called Cherenkov radiation. I'm just wondering how to use 4-momentum to prove this. Especially, how to write the 4-momentum of a photon in medium? Is its energy still equal to momentum * c ? If so, which step in the above derivation is not valid in the presence of medium?

Comment: In a medium some momentum is transferred to the medium, whatever that is, so your final momentum needs an extra term that can be basically anything you want.

Comment: @JohnRennie, that makes sense! Is it possible to use 4-momentum to derive the angle between the electron's trajectory and the emitted photon? I started with the initial 4-momenta of both electron and medium and final 4-momenta of electron, medium, and photon but got stuck with the derivation.